# Reverse Filter Django Model with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have problem filtering in `django-models` and i am using `django-rest-framework` to work this serialized data.

What i want here is to get all herds record both with animal(s) in which the animal may had a `species_type='Cow'` or an empty herd(s).

This is my models.

**models.py**

```
class Herd(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)


class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    species_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    herd = models.ForeignKey(Herd, related_name='animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = [
            'name', 
            'species_type', 
            'breed'
          ]
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

class HerdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    animals = AnimalSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Herd
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'animals'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
```

This is my viewset which handle all crud operations.

**views.py**

```
class HerdViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Herd.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HerdSerializer
```

Now when i browse the `HerdViewSet` endpoint `/api/herd/` i got the results of all herds with animals or empty herd(s). But the animals in some herd does not filter the `species_type='Cow'` it still returns all animal which belong to that herd whether it `species_type` is goat, sheep, etc..

Comment: where did you make the filter `species_type='Cow'`?

Comment: @Enix hi, it should be here in this line `queryset = Herd.objects.all()` in the viewset but sadly i still dont have any idea how to do this since there is no field animals in my `Herd` model unlike in my `HerdSerializer`.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab If you need all the herd data with animal filtering according to species_type='Cow',then You need to update your model structure and relations between fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by `species_type` from Herd. Because you have defined a `related_name` in the foreign key.

try this

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Herd.objects.annotate(animalCount=Count('animals')).filter(Q(animals__species_type='Cow')|Q(animalCount=0))
```

1. `annotate` is used to add an extra field to the results, so a new field `animalCount` is used to hold how many animals for that herd.
2. `Q` is used to build complicated query condition, so for this case,  `Q(animals__species_type='Cow')|Q(animalCount=0)` means, filter by the animals in the herd with species type 'Cow', or there is no animals in that herd.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi not `animal` but `animals`. it does exist... cos he has defined a `related_name` in `foreign key field`. i have tested this code in my machine...

Comment: @Enix you had a great idea but something is wrong, i cant display an empty herd.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab what do you mean an `empty herd`? you mean the filter result is not existed?

Comment: @Enix the filter result existed, i am able to display all herd with animal in it in which their species_type='Cow' but i would like to display a herd with no animals also.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab so.. you need to filter by `species_type` or the herd is empty? right?

Comment: @Enix yes that is what i am expecting, please help

Comment: @Enix Nice answer.I was going to suggest the same approach with Q.

Comment: Wow! that's great! thanks @Enix. But is there any way also that the animals in the herd is filtered to species_type='Cow'?

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yeah, the `animals` inside the herd is not filtered by default. i got the same issues with you in my project.... still working on how to make the filter inside...

Comment: Oh, hope you can also share me the solution by the chance you make it. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab sure, will update you when there is new progress.. :)